# Getting a substream of a stringstream effectively

Tags: c++, parsing, performance, substring, stringstream

I need to implement a mechanism where I can initialize a vector of my custom class using a text source, where each line of the source is representing one instance of my class. To achieve this, I implemented the `operator >>` for my class and `stringstream`. When I read the source, I go line-by-line and get a substream of my original source, then parse the substream each time. This has three benefits for me. First, this way I can make sure that one line of the text source would represent exactly one instance of my class. Second, as the rest of the line after parsing is ignored, I can safely add any comment in any line of my text source, which would surely get ignored by the parser. And third, I don't need to mention the length of the vector in my original source, since the first time I get a parsing error (I check the `fail` and `bad` bits of the stream to confirm this) I know that the vector declaration is over.

To parse line-by-line, I'm using the following code:

```
std::stringstream       fullStream;
std::stringstream       lineStream;
std::string             str;
bool                    isValid;
myClass                 newInstance;
std::vector < myClass > result;

// Fill fullStream from external source (codepart omitted)
isValid = true;
while ( isValid && ! fullStream.eof ( ) ) {
   std::getline ( fullStream, str );
   lineStream.clear ( );
   lineStream.str ( str );
   lineStream >> newInstance;
   isValid = ! lineStream.fail ( );
   if ( isValid ) {
      result.push_back ( newInstance );
   }
}
```

Although this code works fine, I'm wondering if there was a better way to achieve the same result. Specially, if there was a more efficient way to extract a line from `fullStream` to `lineStream`.

Thanks,
Ádám

Comment: Wouldn't it be much simpler to just scan your input string with iterators, rather than using two if not three different streams? In your place I'd move the logic of your extraction operator to a plain function that took a string iterator pair as arguments and get rid of the streams. I'm convinced that your code would be clearer that way.

Comment: I'm using `operator >>` because this way all the whitespace-management and string->float conversion is handled automatically. I don't know how it would be possible to simply achieve that without using `stringstream`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One obvious alternative would be to have your `operator>>` do line-by-line reading itself, so you don't have to do that externally:

```
class MyClass { 
    // some sort of data to demonstrate the idea:
    int x;
    std::string y;

    friend std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &is, MyClass &m) { 
        std::string temp;
        std::getline(is, temp);
        std::istringstream buffer(temp);
        buffer >> m.x >> m.y;
        return is;
    }
};
```

With that, code to read data from a file becomes a little more straightforward:

```
std::copy(std::istream_iterator<MyClass>(fullStream),
          std::istream_iterator<MyClass>(),
          std::back_inserter(result));
```

Edit: if you don't want to build the line-oriented reading directly into the `operator>>` for `MyClass`, another possibility is to use a proxy class:

```
class LineReader { 
    MyClass object;
public:
    operator MyClass() { return object; }

    friend std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &is, LineReader &d) { 
        std::string line;
        std::getline(is, line);
        std::istringstream buffer(line);
        buffer >> d; // delegate to the object's own stream-oriented reader.
    }
};
```

Then when you want to do line-oriented reading, you *read* objects of the proxy class, but *store* objects of the original class:

```
std::vector<MyClass>((std::istream_iterator<LineReader>(some_stream)), 
                      std::istream_iterator<LineReader>());
```

But, when/if you want to read a stream of objects instead of lines of objects, you use the object's own `operator>>` directly:

```
std::vector<MyClass>((std::istream_iterator<MyClass>(stream),
                      std::istream_iterator<MyClass>());
```

Comment: I don't really like the idea of moving the line-by-line parsing part to the `operator >>` function, as this would prevent me from parsing streams where I don't have line-breaks (which I might need to do in a later state of my project). The problem is that my `MyClass` class is actually an implementation of an N-dimensional point, which I'm using at several parts of my project for different purposes, and I might need to parse multiple points from a single line.

Comment: @Jerry, that first example should read `if( std::getline(is,temp) )`. Never use input without verification!

Comment: @sbi: Yes, quite true. Most of what I post lacks (even close to) sufficient checking for invalid input -- or most other error checking either. Although exception handling helps, real code still often ends up with the real intent almost hidden in a mess of error checking (and this is especially true when dealing with user input).

Answer (score 3):

First, if the code works, it is really only by chance.  The idiomatic 
way of handling this is:

```
std::string line;
while ( std::getline( fullStream, line ) ) {
    std::istringstream lineStream( line );
    lineStream >> newInstance;
    if ( lineStream ) {
        result.push_back( newInstance );
    } else {
        fullStream.setstate( std::ios_base::failbit );
    }
}
```

Checking `eof()` before a read is rarely useful, and not checking the
results of your `getline` before using it is almost certainly an error.
Trying to reuse a `stringstream` is more complex and error prone than
simply creating a new one; there is all sorts of state which may or may
not have to be reset.  Streams have a mechanism for memorizing error
state, so you probably want to use this.  (If you want to continue using
`fullStream` for other things after the error, the problem is more
complex, because you've already extracted the line which failed, and you
can't put it back.)  And if you're only reading, you should use
`std::istringstream`, and not `std::stringstream` (which has a lot of
extra baggage); in general, it's very, very rare to use a bi-directional
stream.